# creating page that part of it is fixed and part is dynamic

Tags: html, css

I need the following form will **stretch height**

'div1','div2' and 'div3' need to be fixed hight

panel and 'div4' need to be dynamic hight

'divLeft' need to be near 'divRight'

'vid41','vid42','vid43' size should be dynamic insiden 'div4'

I do not succeed creating page that part of it is fixed and part is dynamic.

How can I do it?

```
<h:form>    
      <div class="mainDiv">
        <div>
          <div>
            <div class="div1"><img /></div>
            <div class="div2">xxx</div>
          </div>
          <div> &nbsp;</div>
          <div class="div3">yyy</div>
          <p:panel> 
          </p:panel>  
          <div class="div4" >
            <div class="divLeft">
               <div class="vid41">
                    ...
               </div>
               <div class="vid42">                  
                  ...                                                                 
               </div>
               <div class="vid43">
                  ...
               </div>    
             </div>
             <div class="divRight">
                 ...
             </div>                     
           </div>   
         </div>  
       </div>
      </div>
    </h:form>
```

Comment: javascript can change attributes after the page has been created.  server-side processors like php or jsp can do this before the user sees it.  which do you need?

Answer (score 0):

To make an element fixed in height, define a height for it. Any element that does not have a height attribute will have a dynamic height (it will fit its' contents).

```
.div1 {
  height: 400px;
}
```

The above CSS will give make div1 400 pixels tall.

Comment: Those that I don't dive them a specific height go one on each other

Comment: Yes, divs are block-style elements, which means they take up all width available and are displayed on their own line by default. If you want to display divs side-by-side you need to set them to inline (`display: inline;`) or float them (`float: left;`). Both  methods have their pros and cons. Learn more about floats [here](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/floatutorial/).
You can also spread them out by using margins or padding e.g. `bottom-margin: 10px;`.